# Laravel Spark Installation Failed on Globally Using Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5, laravel-spark

When I ran the spark installation command to install spark on my global composer directory I got the following error:

```
composer global require "laravel/spark-installer=~1.0"

Changed current directory to /Users/sumon/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/spark-installer ~1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/spark-installer[v1.0.0].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v3.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.0.2
    - laravel/spark-installer v1.0.0 requires symfony/console ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.11, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.12, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.13, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.14, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.15, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.16, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.17, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.18, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.19, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.20, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.21, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.22, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.23, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.24, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.25, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.26, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.27, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.28, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.29, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.30, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.31, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.32, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.33, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.34, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.35, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.36, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.37, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.3.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.4.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.11, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.12, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.11, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.12, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.13, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.6.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.7.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.8.2, v3.0.2].
    - Installation request for symfony/console == 3.0.2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

However, I don't want to remove the `symphony/console` v3.0.2 as this required by the Laravel. So, is there any other way to install the Laravel Spark correctly without removing the `symphony/console` v3.0.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've `symfony/console` v3.0.2 installed globally with composer and spark require `symfony/console` v2.8.2 as such I was experience the issue. The issue is now resolved after I've removed the higher `symfony/console` v.3.0.2.